# Extracting a sub-string from a Variable in C Shell Script?

Tags: windows, shell

I am absolutely new to C Shell Script (.csh). I dont know why the following script is not working properly.

```
set Version;
wmic /append: "$Version" wmic os get version;    #This prints: Version
                                                  6.1.7601
echo $Version;    #This does not print anything as $Version is empty
set subVersion = `echo $Version | awk '{print substr($0,2)}'`;
echo $subVersion;    #This does not print anything
```

Please help me know what is wrong with the script.
Thank You.

UPDATE: Looks like what was being printed was actually by the line `wmic /append: "$Version" wmic os get version;` & not `echo $Version;`.
So the question now is how do I get the output from wmic into the variable `$Version` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code helps in catching the output to a variable. Now its possible to do anything with the variable:

```
set Ver = `(wmic os get version)`;
echo $Ver;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't test it but here are a few alternatives:

```
`echo $Version | awk 'BEGIN {FS=".";} {print $1;}'`;
```

so use the field splitting feature of awk to get what you need. awk is a bit of an overkill:

```
set subVersion = ${Version:0:2}
```

should also work.

Comment: Hey user1666959 thanks for answering!
Just found out that $Version was an empty string.
What was being displayed in shell was actually printed by the line: **wmic /append: "$Version" wmic os get version;**
Can you please tell me how to catch the output from wmic into the variable $Version?

Comment: set xx = `wmic ...` should work. Or in a bash like shell set xx = $(wmic ...)

Comment: Hey @user what you say does not work either! Please take a look at my answer.